# For an orthonormal set in $L^{2}[0,1]$, show that $ \int_{A} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_{k}(x)|^{2} \geq 1$ for a non-zero measurable subset $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I was stuck on the following question

> If ${f_1, f_2, . . . }$ is a complete orthonormal set in $L^2
> [0, 1]$ and $A$ is an arbitrary subset of
>   positive Lebesgue measure in [$0,1]$ show that
>   $$ \int_{A} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  |f_{k}(x)|^{2} \geq 1$$

What I tried so far is to use to monotone convergence theorem to interchange the sum and the integral so what we are left with showing is 
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{A} |f_{k}(x)|^{2} \geq 1$$
I tried to assume the contrary that 
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{A} |f_{k}(x)|^{2} < 1$$
to that end I see that $f_{k}$ eventually vanishes on $A$ for large enough $k$, but I don't see how to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove it directly.

We have $1_A = \sum_k \langle f_k, 1_A \rangle f_k$ (in an $L^2$ sense) and Parseval
combined with Cauchy Schwarz & Tonelli gives
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mu(A)} &=& \|1_A\|_2^2 \\
&=& \sum_k |\langle f_k, 1_A \rangle |^2 \\
&=& \sum_k |\langle f_k \cdot 1_A, 1_A \rangle |^2 \\
&\le &
\sum_k \|1_A\|_2^2 \|f_k \cdot 1_A \|_2^2  \\
&=&
\mu(A) \sum_k \int_A |f_k(x)|^2 dx \\
&=&  \mu(A) \int_A \sum_k |f_k(x)|^2dx
\end{eqnarray}
Noting that $\mu(A) >0$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Does the fact that $1_A = \sum_k \langle f_k, 1_A \rangle f_k$ follow from $f_{k}$ being a complete orthonormal basis? If so, is this a standard result found in most books?

Comment: Yes.  ${}{}{}{}$